# Two constraints setting together in optimization problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, constraints

I am working on an optimization problem, and facing difficulty setting up two constraints together in Python. Hereunder, I am simplifying my problem by calculation of area and volume. Only length can be changed, other parameters should remain the same.

Constraint 1: Maximum area should be 40000m2
Constraint 2: Minimum volume should be 50000m3

Here, I can set values in dataframe by following both constraints one-by-one, how to modify code so that both constraints (1 & 2) should meet given requirements?
Many Thanks for your time and support!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                    'Length': [1000, 2000, 3000, 5000],
                    'Width': [5, 12, 14, 16],
                    'Depth': [15, 10, 15, 18]})

area = (df['Length'])*(df['Width'])
volume = (df['Length'])*(df['Width'])*(df['Depth'])
print(area)
print(volume)

#Width and Depth are constants, only Length can be change
#Constraint 1: Maximum area should be 40000m2
#Calculation of length parameter by using maximum area, with other given parameters
Constraint_length_a = 40000/ df['Width']
#Constraint 2: Minimum volume should be 50000m3
#Calculation of length parameter by using minimum area, with other given parameters
Constraint_length_v = 50000/ ((df['Width'])*(df['Depth']))


#Setting Length values considering constraint 1
df.at[0, 'Length']=Constraint_length_a[0]
df.at[1, 'Length']=Constraint_length_a[1]  
df.at[2, 'Length']=Constraint_length_a[2]
df.at[2, 'Length']=Constraint_length_a[3]
#Setting Length values considering constraint 2
df.at[0, 'Length']=Constraint_length_v[0]
df.at[1, 'Length']=Constraint_length_v[1]  
df.at[2, 'Length']=Constraint_length_v[2]
df.at[2, 'Length']=Constraint_length_v[3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believed the code below solve the current problem you are facing.
If I can help any further let me know.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                    'Length': [1000, 2000, 3000, 5000],
                    'Width': [5, 12, 14, 16],
                    'Depth': [15, 10, 15, 18]})

area = (df['Length'])*(df['Width'])
volume = (df['Length'])*(df['Width'])*(df['Depth'])

    
def constraint1(df, col, n):
    df.loc[:n,'lenght'] = 40000 / df.loc[:n, col]
    df.drop('Length', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df

def constraint2(df, col, col1, n):
    df.loc[:n, 'lenght'] = 50000/ ((df.loc[:n,col])*(df.loc[:n,col1]))
    df.drop('Length', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df
```

If you want to performance it through the whole column then

```
def constraint1a(df, col):
    df['lenght'] = 40000 / df[col]
    df.drop('Length', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df

def constraint2a(df, col, col1):
    df['lenght'] = 50000/ ((df[col])*(df[col1]))
    df.drop('Length', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df
    
df = constraint1(df, 'Width', 3)
df1 = constraint2(df, 'Width','Depth', 3)

df2 = constraint1a(df, 'Width')
df3 = constraint2a(df, 'Width','Depth')
```

Adding the conditions I left out the first time

```
def constraint1(df, col, col1):
    l = []
    for x, w in zip(df[col], df[col1]):
        if x > 40000:
            l.append(40000 / w)
        else:
            l.append(x)
    df[col] = l
       
    return df

def constraint2(df, col, col1, col2):
    l = []
    for x, w, d in zip(df[col], df[col1], df[col2]):
        if x <= 50000:
            l.append(50000 / (w*d))
        else:
            l.append(x)
    df[col] = l

    return df
    
df1 = constraint1(df, 'Length', 'Width')
df2 = constraint2(df, 'Length', 'Width', 'Depth')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and support. Both constraints are working but a small modification is required. Const 1 should not need to change the length parameter if value of area is less than 40000, similarly,  Const 2 should not need to change the length parameter if value of volume is greater than 50000. Once again, thanks.

Comment: oh I see. I will fix it and then you can mark the answer as correct. No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Many thanks once again for your time. If I am not wrong current constraints search values larger than x in columns of Length, Width and Depth, instead of area and volume. As I tested these constraints, variable length did not change, even, though values of area and volume are larger than 40000 and less than 50000. Should it be looped through the column of area or volume? and then if condition should be applied? I really appreciate your support.

Comment: @Husnain could you please copy here what you are doing exactly? Because it worked just fine for me here, as I tested it before added the modified part in the answer. I need to see exactly what you are doing to understand why this is not working for you.

Comment: @Husnain copy the  code and do exactly as I did this line will apply the function
df1 = constraint1(df, 'Length', 'Width')

Comment: Thank you very much. I am testing it and let you know if I will face any problems.

Comment: I am very grateful for your time and support.